# Подсветка input в форме авторизации

Tags: input, браузер

В хроме, например, если сохранён пароль, то он подсвечивает инпуты мерзким жёлтым.. это можно как-то убрать, но при этом чтобы пароль всё равно сохранялся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого вопроса есть решение на stackoverflow: [Google Chrome form autofill and its yellow background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6680319/1941460). Это единственное решение которое оставляет возможность сохранения пароля.

```
(function($) {
    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") >= 0)
    {
        var _interval = window.setInterval(function ()
        {
            var autofills = $('input:-webkit-autofill');
            if (autofills.length > 0)
            {
                window.clearInterval(_interval); // stop polling
                autofills.each(function()
                {
                    var clone = $(this).clone(true, true);
                    $(this).after(clone).remove();
                });
            }
        }, 20);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Ахренеть... Работает

Answer (score 0):

Мне пока видятся два варианта:

1. скрытые настройки в: chrome://flags, chrome://settings, ...
2. кастомизация внешенего вида с помощью тем.

Думаю, второй вариант наверняка поможет, вот только это как пушкой по воробьям. Если есть возможность задания пользовательских стилей, то попробуйте поиграться со свойством border.

Comment: То есть с точки зрения веб-разработчика я никак не смогу это убрать, чтобы ни у кого не подсвечивалось?

Comment: Можете еще влиять с помощью JS, ну как плейсхолдеры эмулируются.